# How to redirect some routes of an aws domain to Api Gateway and others to Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'm a bit new to aws, I have a problem. I have a nestjs api deployed on EC2 and accessible through Application Load Balancer. Additionally I have a Serverless Api with Lambdas accessible through Api gateway.

I have configured my domain in Route 53 and I have also successfully configured it in API Gateway

But I need to use the same domain (Exactly the same domain, I don't need to set up subdomains) and that some routes of my api point to API Gateway and others to Application Load Balancer.

Is it possible to do this on AWS? How can I get it?
Thanks for your help.

I need to configure something like that

[www.mydomain.com/books](http://www.mydomain.com/books)  ->  Api Gateway

[www.mydomain.com/students](http://www.mydomain.com/students) ->  Api Gateway

[www.mydomain.com/teachers](http://www.mydomain.com/teachers) -> Applicaion Load Balancer

[www.mydomain.com/grades](http://www.mydomain.com/grades) ->  Application Load Balancer

Answer (score 0):

You could create an AWS CloudFront distribution for your domain, and [configure multiple origins](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/) (API Gateway and the Load Balancer) in CloudFront